# URL duplicating after migrating domain

Tags: url-rewriting

I just set my CNAME to set my subdomain name and now, my WP site that was working has a weird thing, a lot of URL are broken...

All menu links are OK, but all ressources url are not ok.

The new bad url format is:

```
http://example.com/example.com
http://example.com/wp-admin/example.com
http://example.com/example.com/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selector.css?v=3.3.8
```

So, basically, the whole site is broken, and I can't even login the the admin to try to fix it.

Any Idea what's happening???

Answer (score 0):

In the wp_option table, I change site_url and home to the new url, but I forgot to prefix http://

In case it happens to somebody else, it could save you hours !!!